# No Output with DataInputStream

Tags: java, android, stream

Estou tentando construir uma aplicação que funcione como um emulador de terminal, porém simplesmente não é gerada nenhuma saída.

Aqui está o meu código, pode ser útil:

```
package me.craftygaming.TermDroid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import me.craftygaming.TermDroid.R;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by ********* on 11/01/17.
 */
public class ActivityTerminal extends Activity {
    TextView console;
    EditText cmd;
    DataOutputStream os;
    DataInputStream is;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.Activityterminal);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("me.craftygaming.TDroid.MODE");
        String args = intent.getStringExtra("me.craftygaming.TDroid.ARGS");
        File f = new File(message);
        File term = new File(f, "system/bin/python");

        System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
        console = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.console);
        cmd = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.command);

        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/sh -");
            os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
            is = new DataInputStream(p.getInputStream());

            os.writeBytes(term.getCanonicalPath()+"\n");
            os.writeBytes("echo \"Hi\"\n");
        }catch(IOException ex){}
        updater.start();

    }
    public void Submit(View view){
        try{
      String comand = cmd.getText().toString();
        os.writeBytes(comand);
            console.append("\n>> "+comand+"\n");
            cmd.setText("");
            } catch (IOException e){

                CharSequence text = "Error! "+e.getLocalizedMessage();
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, duration);
                toast.show();
            }
    }
    Thread updater = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true){
                try {
                    while (is.available() == 0) {
                    }
                    console.append(is.readUTF() + "\n");
                }catch(IOException e){
                    console.append("ERROR READING!");
                }
            }

        }
    };
}
```

Além disso, existe alguma forma melhor para obter os dados de `DataInputStream`?

Comment: No codigo em questão você não está lendo nada da `InputStream`. A idéia é que, após executar o comando sua aplicação tenha alguma espécie de loop para ler os resultados para uma `String` ou `StringBuilder` e então escrever o resultado na `TextView`. De uma olhada [nesse Exemplo do SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8150065/664577).

Comment: Veja que construir um emulador de terminal do zero não costuma ser uma tarefa trivial. Talvez valha a pena dar uma lida dar uma lida em algum projeto open source como o [Terminal Emulator for Android](https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator).

Comment: Oops, eu ia postar no StackOverflow em ingles, mas acabei postando no em português :D. @AnthonyAccioly O Loop esta no Thread updater.

Comment: Isso está estranho GabrielTk, eu entendi sua tentativa de ler o retorno do comando em uma outra Thread, mas essa construção toda, desde a forma como você está tentando obter o paralelismo até o uso de um `while` dentro do outro para "esperar" pela saída não faz muito sentido e está sujeito a erros. De novo, eu não quero te desestimular se isso for um exercício pessoal, mas se a ideia for criar um emulador de terminal para valer eu diria para você dar uma lida no código do emulador acima ou algo com o [QPython](http://qpython.com/).

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly é mais para um exercício pessoal mesmo. Mas eu não entendo... Qual é o jeito certo de ler o output e mandá-lo para o TextView?? Desculpe, sou mais do C#.

Comment: Oi Gabriel, segue um *hack* de como executar e obter o retorno de comandos no *bash*: [Resposta no SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3644288/664577). Veja que a solução é bem limitada, sem paralelismo, abusando do Ctrl+Z, etc.

Comment: Quanto a jogar em uma *textView*, `append` vai funcionar até você começar  a perceber que é necessário limitar o tamanho do *buffer*, emular sequências de escape, redimensionar a tela, etc. Na prática, para problemas reais você vai precisar de uma view customizada.